# $1003 in 68HC11 input values

Tags: mcu

This is the link to the reference:

https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/M68HC11E.pdf

[image]

I think it is related to the statement "I/O pins configured as high-impedance inputs have port data that is indeterminate."

Does it mean it can generate random input too?

original message:

Whenever I boot the HC11. I always got a value in special register $1003 which is the i/o input (see below). $1000-$103F is the Memory Mapped IO peripheral adress in 68HC11E9. The value of $1003 is either C0, E0, or 80. Where is it coming from? The PortC input and output pins in the HC11 are not connected to anything.

See the following screen. When it is in E0. BUFALLO entry point FFAC (which is "read from i/o device to register A'" seems to change it to C0, but it doesn't change other. Is it related to "indeterminate after reset"? What caused this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would you mind to provide a schematic, or at least a URL to it?

Comment: Figure B-1 shows the schematic of the EVBU. Is this what you have and use? Can you confirm that _nothing_ is connected to PC0 to PC7? The schematic is just one page, but the bus `MCU [2...52]` seems to lead to a not shown additional part.

Comment: My gosh, I was able to load the entire main memory into a file after I figured out the vcc was not connected right in the JTAG. I was surprised they didn't blow the JTAG fuse. Maybe I'm the only one who has loaded it. Unfortunately. I'm permanently banned in Electrical Eng. stack becuase people don't like my questions. And I can't ask this at Texas Instrument forum too because only company people can participate. Therefore I have real last question for you. What is your favorite Texas hex file to assembly (or c) language just like m68dis in Hc11? I want to load it and learn the Msp430 codes.TY

Comment: Oh dear, what did you do wrong to be banned? Didn't you respect the rules of StackExchange? It helps to read the hints given. -- And you are doing some frowned-upon things here, again. Do not "capture" some arbitrary question to ask something else. Do not ask for recommendations. This is not a forum. -- Anyway, I don't use MSP430, and therefore have no favorites. You might need to check and learn the tools _you_ use to program MSP430, or use your web search skills to find for example [Ghidra](https://ghidra-sre.org/).